# If $Z$ is $G_\delta$ in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ , then is $\pi_0 [Z]$ a $G_\delta$ in $[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

Writing $Z=\bigcap_{n\in\omega} U_n$, where each $U_n$ is open in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, I hope to show $$\pi_0 [Z]=\bigcap_{n\in\omega} \pi_0[U_n].$$

Is this true? The projection map is open, so that would do it.

Clearly $\subseteq$ holds. My idea for $\supseteq$ is to suppose there is a point $p$ in the intersection that is not in $\pi_0[Z]$. There is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $(p,x_n)\in U_n$. This sequence must have a convergent subsequence, which converges to, say, $x$.  I'd like to show $(p,x)\in\bigcap U_n$, giving a contradiction.

Comment: If $\pi_0$ projection in the first coordinate?

Comment: @ForeverMozart: I just found a counterexample to the real conjecture, not just to the approach that you were trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U_n$ be the intersection with $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ of an open strip of width $2^{-n}$ centred on the line $y=2^{-n}x$; then $\bigcap_{n\in\omega}U_n=\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$, but $\pi_0[U_n]=[0,1]$ for each $n\in\omega$.

**Added:** Let $\{q_n:n\in\omega\}$ be an enumeration of $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]\}$, and let $Z=\{\langle q_n,2^{-n}\rangle:n\in\omega\}$. $Z$ is a countable, relatively discrete subset of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, so it’s a $G_\delta$ in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, but $\pi_0[Z]=\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$, which is not a $G_\delta$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: ah, of course.  thanks.  You could also get an example where the projection is one-to-one, right? Just take the lines you described, and then intersect a bunch of those open strips to show it is $G_\delta$.

Comment: @ForeverMozart: I’m not sure what you’re describing. You mean observe that the singleton of the origin is the intersection of countably many $G_\delta$s, each of which is mapped homeomorphically onto $[0,1]$ by $\pi_0$?

Comment: @ForeverMozart: It is in my example, since $Z$ is a singleton. Or are we somehow talking at cross purposes here?